# add scaffolded item wizard cannot resolve data model class

Tags: entity-framework, .net-assembly, wizard, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

everyone.

I'm trying to create new Scaffolded item for simple ASP.NET Wep API application which should be based on domain object class and DbContext derivative in separate assembly. The assembly is in the solution, target app has a reference to it (and manually created code which invokes the classes from my lib is build up without any errors) and, obviously, the classes I've mentioned have access modifier public.

The problem is wizard for creating new scaffolded item cannot see my model classes. (By the way, when the model classes were in another ASP.NET MVC5 app the wizard worked well.) I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update5.

How to fix this? Any workaround would be helpful too!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing.

the origin of the problem seems to be that I've move my data model classes from ASP.NET MVC app into my class library in wrong way.

I've not just cut/paste them, but copy-paste, cut-paste (confirmed replacement).
this is the only thing which could cause the problem (although I still don't know the details).

Never the less I've started from the beginning again and cut/past the data model files initially - everything seems to work fine now.